# how to pull images from private registry for training in sagemaker pipelines?

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

set up - sagemaker pipeline to create processing and training steps.
for training step, i want to pull image from a private container registry.
I declare/configure appropirate subnets, vpc config in the estimator object (see below)

```
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor, ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
...

script_processor = ScriptProcessor(command=['python3'],
                image_uri='image_uri',
                role='role_arn',
                instance_count=1,
                instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge', 
)

step_process = ProcessingStep(
        name="ProcessStep",
        processor=script_processor, 
        code = 'src/processing.py'
        input = [ 
                ProcessingInput(
                      input_name="utils"
                      source="src/utils", 
                      destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/src/utils",
                )
)

security_group = ["group_id"]

my_subnets = ["subnet-public", "subnet-private"]

network_config = NetworkConfig(enable_network_isolation=False, 
                               security_group_ids = security_group , 
                               subnets= my_subnets)


#training step 
estimate = Estimator (
  entry_point="src/train.py", 
  ....
  network_config= network_config, 
  ....
  image_uri='private_docker_registry/some_image', 
  ...
 )
```

but the error message i get is =>

```
clienterror : Failed to invoke sagemaker: CreateTrainingJob. 
Error Details: TrainingImageConfig with TrainingRepositoryAccessMode 
set to VPC must be provided when using a training image from a private docker 
registry...
```

sagemaker pipeline documentation doesn't show where to provide this configuration. How to cofigure these two attributes ,  TrainingImageConfig with TrainingRepositoryAccessMode?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below document to adapt the estimator to use custom docker registry other than ECR.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers-adapt-your-own-private-registry.html

Comment: thanks. do you know if there is a way to do the same in sagemaker pipeline?